# why is the blueprint route not found with a registered url_prefix

Tags: python, flask

I have a file that registers a blueprint and runs the app `api/v1/app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""returns api status code"""

from api.v1.views import app_views
from flask import Flask
from models import storage
from os import getenv

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(app_views, url_prefix="/api/v1")


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_session(session):
    """close a session"""
    storage.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = getenv('HBNB_API_HOST') if getenv('HBNB_API_HOST') else '0.0.0.0'
    port = getenv('HBNB_API_PORT') if getenv('HBNB_API_PORT') else 5000
    app.run(port=port, host=host, threaded=True)
```

a file that creates a blueprint `api/v1/views/__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""create a blueprint"""

from flask import Blueprint

app_views = Blueprint("app_views", __name__)
```

and a file that creates a blueprint route `api/v1/views/index.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""returns api status code"""

from flask import jsonify
from api.v1.views import app_views


@app_views.route('/status')
def status():
    """return ok response"""
    return jsonify({"status": "OK"})
```

i registered the blueprint with the url_prefix /api/v1, but when i try to access http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/status, I get 404.

So what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You defined the prefix correctly. The problem here is because the file `api/v1/views/index.py` was never interpreted. If you add `import api/v1/views/index.py` in the file `api/v1/app.py` it will probably work

Comment: thanks that worked.. I was told to wildcard import from index.py in the __init__.py file but that led to a circular import error